# Unity: Will a 2D animator controller load all sprites for all animations into memory?

Tags: unity

I've got a massive animator controller for my main character in my 2D game. I want to know if my animator controller will load every animation for my main character all at once since all of his animation clips are in the controller. That would represent a huge number of sprites. The game uses sprite animation.

Comment: What does your profiler tell you?

Comment: I don't have all my animations available to test with.  That's why I have to ask.  I want to avoid mistakes before I make them.

Comment: That's fine. Grab any old image, copy it a dozen times, and do a quick synthetic test. You'll find your answer faster than waiting for a stranger to do this test on your behalf.

Comment: The other reason being I figured someone else had probably run into this before and the whole purpose of this service is to spread knowledge and save time.

Comment: Heck, maybe someone else will have this question, see the answer here, and save themselves hours of work.  It's a good thing.

Comment: In the interest of saving time: imagine you're designing an engine. Would you design it to lazily load sprites, so that a character might disappear or stutter mid-animation if a frame it needs isn't loaded yet? Or would you design it to load all the frames up-front, so that animations are guaranteed to play smoothly and look as intended? ;)

Comment: Ahh ok, I guess that's my answer.  Thanks for your help!  Guess I better break these big guys apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity, all sprites in all animation clips used in an Animator Controller will be pre-loaded into memory.

In other words, it's not a good idea to have all of your animations for a character handled by one Animator Controller if you have lots of animations for that character.

In my case, (2D point and click adventure game), I'm going to have to either break my controllers apart, or start using the Playables API (probably via some third party library like Animancer).

I wish this were documented somewhere, so here's my wish being granted!  Hope this helps someone else.